# What's the proper term for "Organize by subject, with a heading"?

Tags: terminology, generic-term

I've noticed that people usually organize things by

- Grouping things with the same subject/topic together, then
- Putting a short heading at the top.

**What's the proper English word for this kind of organization process?**

Examples:

- Newpaper sections   (business, sport, current affairs)
- Stack Overflow Communities (Programming, English Language & Usage, Physics)
- Libraries (science fiction, horror)
- TV channels (movies, comedy, news)
- Textbook chapters (intro, basics)
- Computer folders (my pictures, my documents etc.)

Comment: Did you try [checking a thesaurus for *organize*](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/organize?s=t) first?

Comment: No, but I did google it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking to [categorise or classify](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/categorize):

> - to arrange in categories or classes; classify.
> - to describe by labeling or giving a name to; characterize.

The Free Dictionary

Comment: +1 In US we seem to use *categorize* more often.